# Selecting a value from an n dimensional array based on a child value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to choose an element in an array based on one of it's children's values.

Using the results returned from the Google Maps API geocode request as an example, we have an array of the form:

```
{
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "Renshaw St",
          "short_name": "Renshaw St",
          "types": [
            "route"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Eccles",
          "short_name": "Eccles",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Greater Manchester",
          "short_name": "Gt Man",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "United Kingdom",
          "short_name": "GB",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "M30 0PQ",
          "short_name": "M30 0PQ",
          "types": [
            "postal_code"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Manchester",
          "short_name": "Manchester",
          "types": [
            "postal_town"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "Renshaw St, Eccles, Manchester, Greater Manchester M30 0PQ, UK",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 53.48266090000001,
            "lng": -2.35206530
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 53.48128999999999,
            "lng": -2.35324410
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 53.4822450,
          "lng": -2.35294730
        },
        "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 53.48332443029150,
            "lng": -2.351305719708498
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 53.48062646970850,
            "lng": -2.354003680291502
          }
        }
      },
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    }
```

I'd like to choose the `address_component->long_name` that has the element `type` equal to a value I specify.

I have written the following code that takes the above `array` and a `key` to find as parameters and seems to work well:

```
function getAddressComponent(key, result) {

  var rtn;

  $.each(result,function(index,value){
    if( result[index].types[0] == key ) rtn = result[index].long_name;
  });

  return rtn;    
}
```

But was wondering if anyone could suggest a better approach as I have seen it done a few different ways and would like to use the optimal one.

Comment: Please show us the real array. I guess you receive JSON, not XML?

Comment: What different ways have you seen?

Comment: Note: the `types` property is an array, which you obviously know since your code has `.types[0]`, but that will only ever test the first type. Perhaps `if(result[index].types.indexOf(key) != -1)` would be a better test? (Noting you may need to allow for [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) with older IE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't that long.. lol. You can return the result immediately because once you found it, you can leave the loop. And I didn't investige the jQuery forEach but it couldn't be shorter than the code below, I reckon.

How is this?

```
function findAdressComponentByLongName( findString ) {

    var addressComponents = data.address_components,
        i = 0,
        ln = addressComponents.length;

    for( ; i < ln; i++ ) {

        if( addressComponents[ i ].long_name == findString ) {

            return addressComponents[ i ];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use jQuery.each, a normal for-loop would be even shorter in here.

```
function getNameByFirstType(key, result) {
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
        if (result[i].types[0] == key)
            return result[i].long_name;
    return false;    
}

getNameByFirstType("country", data.address_components);
```

Also, I'm not sure why you only check the first member of the `types` array - but I guess this is expected behaviour.